# What is the Powershell equivalent of the command "find | grep 'mystring'"?

Tags: powershell, terminal

What is the Powershell equivalent of the command

`find | grep "mystring"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent of `find` in PowerShell is `Get-ChildItem` and the equivalent of `grep` is `Select-String`, so you have:

`Get-ChildItem -Name | Select-String "mystring"`

You can use the common aliases of those commands ( `gci` and `sls`, respectively) to shorten it a bit:

`gci -n | sls "mystring"`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to do follow the folders and just search within a certain folder, you do not need the find and Get-ChildItem.
You can specify PATH to Select-String like this. (same as  >grep "mystring" ./*)

```
PS> Select-String "mystring" .\*

Select-String [-Pattern] <String[]> [-Path] <String[]>

 -Path <String[]>
      Specifies the path to the files to be searched. Wildcards are permitted. The default location is the local directory.
      Specify files in the directory, such as "log1.txt", "*.doc", or "*.*". If you specify only a directory, the command fails.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add a function into your profile here:

```
C:\Users\<username_here>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

Add this code:

```
function findgrep() {
  dir -Filter $args[0] -Recurse | %{$_.FullName} | Resolve-Path -Relative
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
findgrep "*.png"
```

Output is relative to the current directory:

```
.\Documents\My Web Sites\WebSite1\iis.png
.\Documents\My Web Sites\WebSite1\some.png
```